# Respect/disrespect someone as + noun

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What does these form "respect someone as + .." means? What is the meaning of "***as***" in these sentences below?

> 1- You know you are angry because I ***disrespected*** you ***as*** a
>   boss.
>
> 2- I ***respect*** you ***as*** a player and a person and I always
>   have.
>
> 3- An ideal girl first of all needs to know how to ***respect*** you
>   ***as*** a partner.
>
> 4- Be respectable and she will ***respect*** you ***as*** you are a
>   good influence on her son or daughter. (I think here "as" means
>   "because")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the first three sentences, [*as*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as#h4) is a preposition:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **2** : in the capacity, character, condition, or role of
>   // works *as* an editor

In other words, it's possible for somebody to say this:

> I don't respect you *as* an employee, but I do respect you *as* a parent.
>
> → I don't respect you *in the role of* an employee, but I do respect you *in the role of* a parent.

The use of *as* makes it possible to separate out different aspects (or contexts) of somebody's actions. It's the equivalent of saying you like somebody's shoes but dislike their shirt; it doesn't make a generalized statement about the person as a whole, but focuses on something specific.

---

In the fourth sentence only, [*as*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as#h2) is used as a conjunction:

> **7** : for the reason that : BECAUSE, SINCE
>   // stayed home *as* she had no car

As you say, it means:

> Be respectable and she will respect you *because* you are a good influence on her son or daughter.